# System time is not synced with windows

Tags: system, dual-boot, microsoft-windows, time

I have a triple boot operating systems with windows and two linux. each one of them are having different date and times. if I updated at one, then other two's values get messed up.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time wrong since dual-boot installation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8306/time-wrong-since-dual-boot-installation)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - search gave me the following which fixed my issue. Basically your system bios clock setting is the reference point to work from before changing your OS settings.
https://superuser.com/questions/459159/system-clock-is-not-set-correctly-on-startup